# Stop Android Wear Time to Leave Notifications

Tags: notifications, google, android-wear, motorola-moto-360

On my Moto 360, I get time to leave notifications repeatedly. Anytime I have an event on my calendar with a location, I'll get multiple alerts from the Google app about when to leave for it.

So, if I have a dinner at 6pm at a certain restaurant, it'll buzz at least 5 times earlier in the day (often much earlier, like at 1pm that day) telling me the estimated time I need to leave at to arrive on time for the dinner. This is incredibly annoying and I can't figure out how to get it to turn off save for blocking the Google app from sending me notifications at all (something I'd rather not do).

I have time to leave notifications off in the Google app on my phone (Google app -> Settings -> Notifications -> Time to leave -> off) and thus don't get such notifications on my phone (but they do show up on my watch).

Here's what the notifications are like on my watch:

[image]

**How can I stop these notifications from appearing and buzzing my wrist?**

Comment: No answer yet!! Really looking for anything.

Comment: Maybe this [app](https://forum.xda-developers.com/android-wear/development/app-smart-wear-notification-tones-text-t3349211) can help? I don't own a smartwatch to try

Comment: @beeshyams I don't think so :/. It doesn't appear to be able to block notifications, the system vibration for it still vibrates (I can filter out an extra vibration for it though).

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping it coul. Vibration can be controlled through automation app but I don't know how to kill it since it shows up on smartwatch only and not on device

Answer (score -1):

I haven't seen similar issue yet. So, I am not sure of the answer but you can:

Make sure you are on the latest Android Wear app update
Make sure you are on the latest Android Wear watch update
Make sure your watch is paired with your phone or tablet
Check that your phone is connected to the Internet
Make sure your watch isn’t in Theater mode
Make sure that you’re getting notifications on your phone (vibrate mode is on)
Make sure that you’re getting notifications on your phone
Make sure app notifications and system notifications on your phone are turned on
Try restarting your watch
If none of this works, then try  unpairing and pairing again

Another tip that some users experiencing this recommended:

1. Go to the watch -> Settings -> Permissions -> System Permissions -> Google Services Framework -> read instant messages ENABLED.
2. Restart phone and watch.

If Nothing works at all, wait for future updates!
Hope it helps.

Comment: What does allowing Google Services Framework to read instant messages do? Why would I want to enable that?

Comment: Well, I enabled it and I'm still getting Time To Leave notifications, so this doesn't work.